# How do you run custom code and display a dialog box when using Visual Studio installer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, activex, windows-installer, installshield

Looking at VS2010 installer I saw a way to hook in macros and created a test macro but my test macro didn't show up in the list.  I also briefly tested InstallShield LE but it didn't meet all my requirements and I went away for a couple of days and when I returned it said the project had expired.  This is a simple one-off install so I'd rather not spend the $$ for InstallShield pro.

What is the best way to call some custom code and display a dialog box pre/post install within VS2010 or VS2008 installer?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't offer much support for custom actions. When exactly during install do you need to execute them?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I need to check for admin permissions and see if an existing ActiveX is already installed.  I wrote a separate post on these items as they are independently interesting to other readers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281669/ootb-way-to-check-for-admin-permissions-before-running-vs2010-installer-msi

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio setup projects do not support this. To use custom actions before or after the actual installation you can use a different setup authoring tool.

If you want a free solution you can try WiX. It has a steep learning curve, but it gets the job done.

For commercial tools you can see this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a really scalable solution per say but a useful hack when you don't want to spend money for the full featured tools.   You can build your MSI using a Visual Studio Deployment Project or InstallShield LE project and then use post build steps to perform automation to modify the MSI to do things it wasn't authored to do.

If you understand the MSI table data you can edit the MSI in Orca, create a transform, author your dialog and then generate the transform file.   Then everytime you build your MSI you just use a postbuild command to apply that transform to your MSI as if VS authored it.

You might, cough cough, be able to find someone around here to help you do that on the cheap.